# How to set UIScrollView height correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am having issues getting my `UIScrollView` to scroll the way I expect it to. I would like it to be 1,200 points high, and I have managed to get it to scroll to this height, however I am having a couple of problems.

First of all, the content is starting further down the screen that it should be. It looks like it is scrolled down 64 pixels below the navigation bar (the height of the navigation bar). How can I get it so that it starts right below the navigation bar?

Also, I have three buttons in the view that are not calling their functions when tapped. I assume this because I have made a mistake with the size of the `UIScrollView` somehow. The buttons work if I move them inside the main frame (the size of the screen).

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 1200)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I fixed the issue with the buttons. I forgot to set the height of the view that the objects were placed on within the `UIScrollView`. Still haven't fixed the issue with the starting point though, if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you put breakpoints in your code, you will notice that viewDidLayoutSubviews get's called *after* viewDidLoad. effectively, when you are setting scrollView.contentSize in viewDidLoad, the views frame will not be loaded, and because of this CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 1200) will potentially set the content size to {0, 1200}.

You want to move your contentSize code to *after* you update the scrollView frame, inside the viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Regarding the first part of your question, you might want to take a look at UIScrollView's contentInset property.

Hope this helps!